# Filter a View that uses a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a view VW_Checks. I am using STUFF to merge the records in the columns 'Platforme' and 'Systemname' to avoid a long list of redundant data.

the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Checks] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT  DISTINCT C.CheckID AS CheckID, C.CheckTitle as CheckTitle, 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PLATFORMNAME
        FROM dbo.CHECK_PLATFORM CPP
        WHERE CPP.CHECKID = C.CHECKID
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS Platformname,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + SYSTEMNAME
        FROM dbo.CHECK_SYSTEM CSS
        WHERE CSS.CHECKID = C.CHECKID
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS Systemname
FROM dbo.[CHECK] C INNER JOIN               
            dbo.CHECK_CATEGORY CC ON C.CHECKID = CC.CHECKID
            INNER JOIN dbo.CATEGORY CAT ON CC.CATEGORYID = CAT.CATEGORYID
            INNER JOIN dbo.CHECK_SYSTEME CS ON CS.CHECKID = C.CHECKID
            INNER JOIN dbo.CHECK_PLATFORM CP ON CP.CHECKID = C.CHECKID
```

The view is fine as it is (meaning it shows exactly what I want it to show), but when I try to filter my view, it does not work.

example of my problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_Checks VW_C
WHERE CONTAINS(VW_P.Platformname,'iOS')
```

the WHERE clause in the SELECT-statement above does not work at all, as if it's not even there.
Since the `VW_P.Platformname` is a combined column (using a subquery), I can't create a unique index on my view.

the error message when I try to create a unique index:
    `Error: 10127, Severity: 16, Cannot create unique index I_VW_Checks on view VW_Checks because it contains one or more subqueries. Consider changing the view to use only joins instead of subqueries. Alternatively, consider not indexing this view.`

How can I alter my view/add indexes to it so I can filter properly, without losing my combined records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTAINS()` is a statement used with full text indexes.  I suppose you could materialize the view and go through a lot of trouble to create one.  Instead, you could use `like`:

```
WHERE ', ' + (VW_P.Platformname + ', ' like '%, ' + 'iOS' + ', %'
```

I do agree with Gareth that there might be other more efficient ways to do what you want.  However, given this view, `LIKE` makes more sense than `CONTAINS()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but I can't see why you would want to. You are concatenating columns into a single value, then searching this single value for some text. Why not just search the columns before you concatenate them? And add an index to the underlying column if necessary, e.g.

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    vw_Checks AS c
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    CHECK_PLATFORM AS cpp
            WHERE   cpp.Platformname LIKE '%iOS%'
            AND     cpp.CheckID = c.CheckID
        );
```

Or if you have a full text index:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    vw_Checks AS c
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    CHECK_PLATFORM AS cpp
            WHERE   CONTAINS(cpp.Platformname, 'iOS')
            AND     cpp.CheckID = c.CheckID
        );
```